# Абстрактный класс "Музыкальный инструмент"

Tags: c++

В соответствии с вариантом организовать в программе классы. В производных классах не забыть объявление конструкторов.  Функции вывода данных на печать объявить виртуальной в базовом классе и переопределить ее в производных классах. Создать объекты всех классов и продемонстрировать работу всех методов производных классов.

Задание:
Описать абстрактный класс Музыкальный инструмент. Класс должен содержать характеристики: название, фирма-производитель, стоимость, функцию вывода всех данных на экран. На его основе реализовать классы Духовой инструмент, Фортепиано, Струнный инструмент. Задать отдельные характеристики классов, например, год выпуска, количество струн и т.п.  Создать список объектов класса Оркестр, модифицировать его, поместив в его начало все Духовые инструменты.

У меня возникло много проблем с данным заданием и поэтому хочу попросить у вас помощи. 1)Я не могу создать список обьектов класс Оркестр и модифицировать его. Идей просто не приходит. 2)Я вообще не уверен, что сделал всё правильно, как по заданию. Тема на самостоятельное изучение, но проверять будут строго по заданию и хотелось бы спросить вас, выполнил ли я то, что от меня требуется? Заранее огромное спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

//Класс инструменты
class instrument
{
protected:
    char name[30], firm[30];
    int cost;
public:     
    instrument()
    {
        cost=0;
    }
    virtual ~instrument() = default;

    void GetInst()
    {
        cout << "\nВведите название инструмента: "; cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите производителя: "; cin >> firm;
        cout << "Введите цену: "; cin >> cost;
    }

    void PutInst()
    {
        cout << "\nИнструмент: " << name;
        cout << "\nПроизводитель: " << firm;
        cout << "\nЦена: " << cost;     
    }
    virtual void GetData() = 0; 
    virtual void PutData() = 0;
};

//Духовые
class WindInst: public instrument
{
private:
    int year, LC; //LC - Длина канала
    char material[30]; 
public:
    void GetData()
    {
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Длина духового канала: "; cin >> LC;
        cout << "Материал: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nДлина духового канала: " << LC;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;
    }               
};

//Клавишные
class PianoInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, NON; //Количество нот (NON)
    char material[30];
public:
    void GetData()
    {
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Количество нот: "; cin >> NON; if (NON != 7) cout << "Наверное вы ошиблись... " << endl;
        cout << "Ìàòåðèàë: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество нот: " << NON;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;
    }               
};

//Струнные
class StringInst: public instrument
{
private:
    int year, NOS; //Количество струн (NOS)
    char material[30];
    public:

    void GetData()
    {
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Количество струн: "; cin >> NOS;
        cout << "Материал: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество струн: " << NOS;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;    
    }
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    system ("chcp 1251 && cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    instrument* instK[100];
    int n = 0, s = -1;
    bool k = true;
    char choice;
    while(true){
    cout << "     Выберите дальнейшее действие: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Ввод инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "2) Вывод всех инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "3) Оркестр " << endl << endl;
    cout << "0) Выход" << endl << endl;
    cout << "S=";
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    switch(s) {

    //Ввод инструментов
    case 1: {   
    do{
        cout << "Духовой (W), Струнный (S) или Клавишный (P): ";
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 'W')
        instK[n] = new WindInst;

        else if(choice == 'S')
        instK[n] = new StringInst;

        else
        instK[n] = new PianoInst;
        instK[n++] -> GetData();
        cout << "Ещё инструмент (y/n)?";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");
    }
    while(choice == 'y');
    cout << "Вернуться в главное меню?" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Вывод данных
    case 2: {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        instK[j] -> PutData();
    }
    cout << "Вернуться в главное меню?" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Оркестр (Не сделан)
    case 3: {

    cout << "Вернуться в главное меню?" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    break;
    }

    //Выход
    case 0: {
    return 0;
    break;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: после  прочтения первых обьявлений уже возникает вопрос:  если вы пишете иерархию классов, это уже C++, и  лучше вместо С_ строк  иметь строковые обьекты

Comment: Это важно или просто считается хорошим стилем? И будет ли это влиять на работу?

Comment: Это не важно для самого результата  но с точки зрения безопасности, удобства и легкости использования, читабельности и    обьема кода, конечно лучше использовать возможности С++,  и все написать на языке С++.   Если я вам напишу половину на русском, а другую половину на английском, это не будет означать, что я неправильно выражаюсь... Но стоит ли?..

Comment: @Nejdan нет, если все сделано правильно, то на работе этой программы это никак не скажется

Comment: Хорошо, вас понял. Попробую использовать строки. Извините, но не могли бы сразу помочь разобраться с оркестром? Я не совсем понимаю, что от меня требуется в данном случаи. Буду благодарен.

Comment: "класса Оркестр" . Нужен класс оркестр. У Вас  его ещё нет.

Comment: @JaponDemon Создать класс оркестр, в нём вызвать методы вывода инструментов при этом первыми вывести духовые, а потом остальные? Алгоритм такой?

Comment: Класс оркестр со списком инструментов. Вероятно необходимы методы добавления, удаления, поиска и т.д.  Хотя требуется в задаче только "список объектов .... модифицировать.... поместив в его начало все Духовые инструменты"

Comment: Что такое список ?

Comment: вектор, массив или связный список?

Comment: @JaponDemon хороший вопрос. Думаю это массив в данном случаи. Но я не уверен)

Comment: Не нужен никакой класс оркестр. По заданию нужен класс музыкальный инструмент, как базовый, так что у вас все правильно, с некоторыми исключениями

Comment: @ ARHovsepyan Может и не надо но это что простите "класса Оркестр" .

Comment: Или это список, его название Оркестр . Как-то неоднозначно.

Comment: Простите, что моё задание немного двусмысленно, но как дали, так и написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
class instrument
{
protected:
    string name, firm;
    int cost;
public:
     // независимо от того, установили вы данные в ручную или нет, обьект 
     // должен иметь нормальное состояние
    instrument() : name(""), firm(""), cost(0) {}
    virtual ~instrument() = default;
    virtual void setData()
    {
        cout << "введите название инструмента,  фирму,  цену:\n";
        cin >> name >> firm >> cost;
    }

    virtual void PutInst() const
    {
        cout << "\nИнструмент: " << name << endl
             << "\nПроизводитель:  << firm << endl
             << "\nЦена: "*/ << cost << endl;
    }
};

class PianoInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    const int key; //Количество клавиш константное число
    string colour;
public:
    PianoInst() : key(85), colour("black") {}
    void setData() {
        instrument::setData();
        cout << "введите цвет:\n";
        cin >> colour;
    }

    void PutInst() const
    {
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "Количество клавиш: " << key << endl
              << "цвет пианино:     " << colour << endl;
    }
};
```

Я написал только один производный класс, но на его примере по той же логике вы можете написать и другие. Теперь можно написать программу:

```
int main()
{    
    std::list<instrument*>  orchestra;
    PianoInst p;
    p.setData();
    orchestra.emplace_back(&p);
    // дальше создаем другие инструменты, устанавливаем данные
    // и заносим в список анологично обьекту `p`
    // и для всех вызываем функцию печати
    std::for_each(orchestra.begin(), orchestra.end(), 
                  std::mem_fun(&instrument::PutInst));
    return 0;
}
```